# Excel VBA - Application.OnTime not running

Tags: excel, vba

I would like some help to understand why the function **doSomething** is not running.

**Calculation mode is on Automatic**

```
Sub Test()
    check = 0
    
    Debug.Print "Timer_1: " & Now()
    
    Call runFromNow("doSomething", "00:00:05")
    Do While check = 0
        DoEvents
    Loop
    
    Debug.Print "Timer_2: " & Now()
End Sub

Sub runFromNow(myProcedure As String, Optional myTime As Variant = "00:00:15")
    If myProcedure <> "" Then
        Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue(myTime), myProcedure
        Debug.Print "runFromNow: Activated at " & Now + TimeValue(myTime)
    End If
End Sub

Sub doSomething()
    check = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: While this might not be the best way to run the timer like you intend to, you can solve this by making `check` into a global variable. Right now it doesn't work because the `check` inside `Test()` is not the same `check` that is updated in `doSomething()`

Comment: I highly recommend to use `Option Explicit` to avoid such issues. This would force you to declare `check` a second time if it is not declared public. And so you would immediately see that it was only declared private. Especially for beginners `Option Explicit` forces you to write better code.

Comment: Marcucciboy2, if this is not the best way, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to get this one done with declaring a public variable.

I wrote this short test for giving you an example:

```
Public Check As Long

Sub Test()
    
    Call Test_Dam
    
    Debug.Print Check

End Sub

Sub Test_Dam()

    Check = 1

End Sub
```

Your Debug.print will give you the 1 you need ;)